# displaying taxonomy terms on condition

Tags: taxonomy-terms

How should I check if any taxonomy term contains content or nor. for e.g
`parent
 --child1
  --child1.1
  --child1.2
  --child1.3
 --child2
 --child3` 
if let say `child1.1` does not contain any content then this term should not appear in the list. Whenever content is added to the content type having this term reference field it will automatically appear appear in the list.

Comment: In what context? Where is the list appearing? Are you generating the list yourself?

Comment: I misread your question and almost left an answer that didn't work but after re-reading wanted to see if you tried this: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!taxonomy!taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_select_nodes/7 it may be a little overkill but most of the queries should be cached so may be feasible or use part of what the function uses, or try a view

Comment: yes @2pha I generated the list using drupal api function.

Comment: Thanku @burnsjeremy but I think this is not the one what I want.This is used to provide an array for all nodes depending upon the tid provided.

Comment: I think @burnsjeremy means you can use that function to check for nodes after you call taxonomy_get_tree()

Comment: Though you could create your own query to do it.

Comment: Yea @2pha is correct about what I was meaning, when you are looping through your terms to print after you call taxonomy_get_tree, you have the $tid available then, so then just check for if that $tid has any nodes, if it does show the term, if it doesn't don't show the term. He is also correct about writing your own query, that's why I said check the function, it has the query you need. The issue is the way D7 handles taxonomy fields and that function would be the correct query to check a broad range, you could slim it down if you just needed one field I assume.

Comment: That function is how nodes that fall under a certain taxonomy term are loaded btw. So if you hit /taxonomy/term/3 you get content that is associated with that term if there is any, that function does that and builds out the feeds for taxonomy. Just for future reference if anyone needs it

Comment: This link (https://www.waldbeek.com/blog/view-taxonomy-term-and-hide-empty-terms) is how to do this in views. You show all taxonomy for a vocabulary and then add a relationship "Taxonomy Term: Representative Node" and require the relationship. You may be able to use that or the way the query works to see another way in code, I'm more of a code guy myself but views can be in code :) (sometimes)

Comment: If you use the taxonomy_select_nodes() be sure to use the limit param, you could set it to 1 b/c you only need to check to see if that term is being used by a node, if it returns 1 then it would be sufficient for your use case. If not it could get pretty heavy say if you had 100+ nodes on 25 different terms or even higher numbers eeek